# Autosizing button text programmatically

Tags: android, android-button, autosize

I'm creating buttons programmatically and the text is slightly cut-off.
I trying to autosize the text-size but I've only found how to do so in XML:

```
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

but have to to do programmatically and can't figure out how to do so with a button and not a TextView.
I tried the following line:

```
letter.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(10, 100,2, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
```

but it doesn't do anything.

This is how my buttons are created, the width depends on the screen width:

```
Button letter = new Button(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpWidth/10-2, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            btnlp.setMargins(1,15,0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Sample xml. You don't need to program.

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a related method [`setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(int)), but is available starting API26, so I would advice you to use more universal `TextViewCompat`

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView, 
    TextView.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
```

Comment: I tried `letter.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(Button.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);` but it didn't do anything, maybe these methods don't work on buttons, as they're meant for TextViews?

Comment: `Button` is in fact a `TextView` with some custom styling (background set) - check out [source of `Button` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/Button.java), it `extends TextView` (so have all `TextView`s methods) and changes only styling in constructors + two overrides for accessibility service at the bottom. sadly I don't have a clue, maybe the way you are adding these `Button`s matter, who is a parent, which type, and the moment of adding these `View`s...